# .NET Core Global exception handler in console application

Tags: c#, .net, exception, console-application, .net-core

I'm porting an console application to `.NET Core`, and I'm trying to replace this line:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;
```

After reading [this](https://deepumi.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/net-core-porting-challenges/), it seems there is no built-in way to do this.

So my question: is the only way to replace this line surrounding my entire code with a `try/catch`?

By reading [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2999), it seems like there is another way, namely by keep on using `System.AppDomain`, but I can't seem to find this class/method. My only guess was [this library](https://github.com/SamuelEnglard/System.AppDomain), but it clearly states that it should not be used if possible, so I would like not to.

Comment: Not helpful now, but this [will be back in .Net Core 1.2](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6398)

Comment: 1.2 was renamed to 2.0.  It was supposed to ship in VS2017 but they didn't get it done in time.  Current goal for "zero bugs" is May 10th.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're right, the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` or it's analog [will be available only in .Net Core 2.0](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.AppDomain.UnhandledException), so for now you should either wait or add additional `try/catch` blocks. However, if you're using the tasks, you can use [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2015/08/10/tpl-exception-handling-and-unobservedtaskexception-issue/), which [is available from first version](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException) of `.Net Core`.

Answer (score 0):

This works now, so for anyone looking to globally handle exceptions in recent versions of .NET Core (e.g., .NET 6), it's the same code used in the old .NET Framework:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleGlobalException;
        throw new Exception("Fatal!");
    }

    static void HandleGlobalException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

Also works fine if your console app is using [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += HandleGlobalException;
throw new Exception("Fatal!");

static void HandleGlobalException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```