Call azure http function but don't wait for it's response
 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
 {
     MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
     {
         { new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), "file", file.FileName }
     };

     _ = httpClient.PostAsync("azure http function url here", formData);
   
 }

This is the code I'm working on, it is not waiting for the response to complete now. But the problem is, the request never arrives at the azure function url. If I await it, it does receives request.
Reason behind I don't want to wait for it's request is because azure http function takes times to complete and I don't want to wait for it to complete.
Something like queue trigger but I need to send file (blob storage is out of requirement so not using Queue trigger)

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) - off to a suspicious start ... You may search for "fire and forget" http calls. The problem here could be that by not awaiting the call, you immediately dispose the Client which in turn cancels (?) the request or most probably doesn't even start the call.

Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50756551/982149

await doesn't mean not waiting for the response to complete. You always should await async methods.

If you use await then client will only dispose after getting response when you are using using

It feels like you have the architecture the wrong way around. You might be better having the HTTP Trigger Function just putting the data into an Azure Queue and returning immediately, so that your caller can properly await the HTTP call. You can't avoid awaiting (or blocking, if not using await) on the HTTP call. Do you want me to post an answer demonstrating how to make the HTTP Trigger return quickly, using a Queue to do the long-running task?
